# OOTB SharePoint List Filter web part on Yes/No type field

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-list-filter, yes-no-field, boolean-field

I have one custom list with Yes/No type field in our SharePoint site(tried both on 2013 and 2016 on premise).

I did below steps:

1. Created one page.
2. Added OOTB SharePoint List Filter web part on Yes/No type field.
3. Added List web part of the same list.
4. Connected this web part with same field on List web Part.

And When I tried to filter the data in List web part by selecting Yes or No choice from filter dropdown, For both choices it is showing me the items with value "No" selected only.

Is it a bug or is there something I am missing to configure to get it working??

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm also getting the same output as you get, might be a bug.

Comment: Yes, you can use "Choice Filter" or "HTML Form Web Part" by adding Dropdown as a work around for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue. The Yes/No value is `1` or `0`.

It can not be compare to boolean type `true/false` or string type `Yes/No`.

You can use a Choice Filter instead, like given below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Adding to your answer, we don't need to provide (empty) as choice. we can add it from "Advanced Filter Options" in web part properties.

Comment: Also, we can use "HTMl Form Web Part" with some HTML Coding (By adding Dropdown with values 1 and 0).